# Can't rename file after svn update by batch

Tags: batch-file, svn, tortoisesvn

I want to do svn update and rename the file with version by batch file:

```
@echo off

CD C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\
START TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"<path>" /closeonend:2

set url=<url>
for /f "tokens=2* delims=:" %%v in ('"svn info %url% | find "Last Changed Rev: ""') do set VERSION=%%v
set "VERSION=%VERSION: =%"

ren "A.docx" "A_v%VERSION%.docx"
```

And found it can't do the rename action, the cmd shows: `The system cannot find the file specified.`

But, if I split the code to two batch, i.e., one for svn update, and one for rename, then it works.
Can't understand why?

Comment: Try `start /w "" Tortoise....` - incluing the empty double-quoted string.

Comment: You can remove the line ```CD C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\```, _(which should technically have been `CD /D "%ProgramFiles%\TortoiseSVN\bin"`)_, and change `TortoiseProc.exe` to `"%ProgramFiles%\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe"`. Change `tokens=2*` to `tokens=1*`,  and `set VERSION=%%v` to `set "VERSION=%%w"`. You can also remove `set "VERSION=%VERSION: =%"` and change `ren "A.docx" "A_v%VERSION%.docx" ` to `ren "A.docx" "A_v%VERSION: =%.docx" `.

Comment: @Compo I've tried, the cmd shows: `Invalid switch - "/command:update".
The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Did you follow the advice in the opening comment? You definitely need to use the empty title string from it! ```Start "" /Wait "%ProgramFiles%\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe"...```.

Comment: @Compo thx, i add the comment from Magoo, the batch can works

Comment: Update: when I use `tokens=1*`, the version shows `LastChangedRev`, should i change it back to `tokens=2*` ?

Comment: Did you not read? You were told to use  `set "VERSION=%%w"` along with it.

Comment: Sorry, i've missed. Only add " ", the part changed from `v` to `w` was not modified.

Comment: Friendly reminder to post an *answer* once all issues have been addressed. Stitching a batch file together from individual comments is obviously a bit cumbersome.

Comment: BTW, if `svn.exe` is not added to your `%Path%`, don't remove ```CD C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\```, just change it to `CD /D "%ProgramFiles%\TortoiseSVN\bin"`, use `Start "" /Wait TortoiseProc.exe...` instead of `Start "" /Wait "%ProgramFiles%\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe"...`, and for additional robustness change `svn` to `svn.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the comment of Magoo and Compo, the batch below can do svn update & rename actions.

```bash
@echo off

CD /D "%ProgramFiles%\TortoiseSVN\bin"
start /w "" "TortoiseProc.exe" /command:update /path:"<path>" /closeonend:2

set "url=<url>"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%v in ('"svn.exe info %url% | find "Last Changed Rev: ""') do set "VERSION=%%w"

ren "A.docx" "A_v%VERSION: =%.docx"
```

Comment: I think, `start /w ""` can be simply removed from the beginning of the fourth line. It is the default execution behavior of `cmd` on processing a batch file to start an executable like `TortoiseProc.exe` and wait for its self-termination before processing of the batch file is continued by `cmd.exe`. The `for` command line could be better coded as `for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%v in ('svn.exe info "%url%" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "Last Changed Rev: "') do set "VERSION=%%w"` if the string assigned to the environment variable `url` does not begin and end with `"`.